# Cmake debug option

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I may have just search really bad but I didn't find this information. I'm used to Makefile but how do I use the otion "-g" and "-Wall" in Cmake with catkin ? I try writing a really dumb program with a memory leak and to run it with valgrind but I have the following

```
==20197== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==20197==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20197==    by 0x400845: main (in /home/ros/groovy_ws/catkin_ws/devel/lib/stalker/debug)
```

And so no line numbers...

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155581/cmake-debug-option/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will set `-g` for you:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

I think `-Wall` is set automatically.

Here are come useful CMake variables: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-21**:
Thanks a lot ! I've been searching exactly for that !